# Twilio Programmable Chat - Stop download / upload of media file

Tags: android, twilio

I was trying to send a media file using Twilio Programmable Chat on an Android App. I wanted to implement a function to stop the download (or upload) of a media file sent in a chat ... before the process is completed. In the documentation I did not find a way to stop the download / upload operation.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask if you then update your questions following that guide you will get much better (more useful) responses!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have a pretty straightforward answer for you here. There is no function in the SDK to stop the upload of media sent in a chat. There are plans for this functionality, but no ETA right now.